# Get the width of the rectangle in the plot created using matplootlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I get the size (width and height) of the rectangle of a plot create with matplotlib's pyplot library. Specifically I need the width of the box:
[image]

Here is a part of the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                           
plt.figure()                                                  
bar_plot = plt.bar(df.index, df_mean, yerr=df_std*1.96, color=colors);
```

Comment: Have you tried `fig.get_size_inches()*fig.dpi` ?

Comment: @Smectic : It seems you copied the answer from the duplicate I marked. In such cases, you should have also included what `fig` is i.e., `fig = plt.figure()`

Comment: I use it recently but I don't know is the output give the size with or without the labels. But your link gave me the answer. Thx

Comment: @Sheldore I think it returns the entire figure size not the rectangle box's size, right?

Comment: @Tahlil I check a plot having `array([314., 192.])` as the output of `fig.get_size_inches()*fig.dpi` and measured it using Inkscape. The value correspond to the entire size of the plot not the box

Answer (score 0):

You can get the with of the box using

```
ax.get_window_extent().transformed(ax.get_figure().dpi_scale_trans.inverted()).width*ax.get_figure().dpi
```